# Ideal approach to subscribing to / dynamically muting many audio streams in a WebRTC room?

Tags: audio, webrtc, opentok

We're building a video chatroom experience using [OpenTok](https://tokbox.com/developer/) and while we have the fundamentals working, I'm finding that the noise floor is super high when we have many participants in the room publishing audio. Off-browser solutions like Zoom do not seem to have this high level of "white noise", but we seem to still be able to hear each participant immediately.

A secondary problem we're attempting to solve is that of the sheer number of subscriptions required: we're capped by OpenTok's [limit](https://support.tokbox.com/hc/en-us/articles/360029413432-How-many-participants-are-supported-in-a-session-) of 3000 subscriptions per room. Currently, every client subscribes to every publisher's feed.

While experimenting with different approaches, it occurred to me that this is something all video chat applications would have to solve. Is there an optimal way to approach this currently? I can see the following solutions:

1. Mute the stream on the publisher side, essentially [streaming silence](https://github.com/meetecho/janus-gateway/issues/620#issuecomment-248239489) until our voice activity detection (VAD) algorithm triggers.
2. Mute the stream on the subscriber side until VAD triggers. Because VAD is done on the publisher side, we risk losing the start of their audio.
3. Only subscribe to streams when VAD triggers. This is like the previous solution, but helps reduce our subscription count. However, I believe the latency and non-determinism here (each client would be individually subscribing, and this likely will be faster for some clients than others)  would mean we'd certainly lose the start of speech.

What's the best way to approach this currently with WebRTC? We're targeting Chrome, Firefox, and Safari.

Answer (score 1):

OpenTok Developer Advocate here.

What timing... I literally just wrote a blog post about this: [Best Practices for Multi-Party Video Conferencing with the Vonage Video API](https://www.nexmo.com/blog/2020/07/23/best-practices-for-multi-party-video-conferencing-with-the-vonage-video-api-dr)

I think it covers most, if not all, your questions. Also, be sure to join the [Vonage Community Slack](https://developer.nexmo.com/slack) where our entire team & community can help.

Answer (score 0):

A one place solution to your problem is OBS,( https://obsproject.com/ ) I guess you know it.

If you dont or if you have used it less, I would like to tell you that, it has immense feature if you explore it correctly and i feel that It will solve your need.

Do use and let me know if your problem is solved, or comment if its not solved.